# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error when Booking a Hotel with Amadeus API

Tags: python, django, fastapi, amadeus

I'm working on integrating the Amadeus API into my application to allow users to book hotels. However, I'm encountering a 500 Internal Server Error when attempting to book a hotel using the provided offer ID.

Here's a simplified version of my Python code:

```py
@app.post("/book_hotel")
async def book_hotel(
    offer_id: str = Query(..., description="Offer ID")
):
    try:
        # Confirm availability of a given offer
        offer_availability = amadeus.shopping.hotel_offer_search(offer_id).get()
        if offer_availability.status_code == 200:
            guests = [
                {
                    'id': 1,
                    'name': {'title': 'MR', 'firstName': 'BOB', 'lastName': 'SMITH'},
                    'contact': {'phone': '+33679278416', 'email': 'bob.smith@email.com'}
                }
            ]

            payments = {
                'id': 1,
                'method': 'creditCard',
                'card': {
                    'vendorCode': 'VI',
                    'cardNumber': '4151289722471370',
                    'expiryDate': '2023-08'
                }
            }

            booking = amadeus.booking.hotel_bookings.post(offer_id, guests, payments).data
        else:
            return {"response": 'The room is not available'}
    except ResponseError as error:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(error.response.body))

    return {
        "id": booking[0]['id'],
        "providerConfirmationId": booking[0]['providerConfirmationId']
    }
```

I'm providing a valid offer ID, '8ANZ20L7F2', but I'm consistently getting a 500 error. I've checked my API credentials, and they seem to be correct.

What could be causing this 500 Internal Server Error when trying to book a hotel with the Amadeus API? Are there any common issues or troubleshooting steps I should consider?

The other endpoints for fetching data and so work as expected, only this is the problem!

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is _your code_ generating the 500 error, or is that the response you're getting from the server? Attach a de bugger at the `except` part and look at what is actually being generated as an error (or even better, _don't_ wrap it in an exception try/except clause when you're swallowing large exceptions - instead just let them bubble up and see what they actually say.

Comment: Why are you passing both `guests` and `payments` as arguments to `post()`?  I think that may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why you receive 500:

- When it comes to booking a hotel in the test environment, your request is being sent to each hotel provider and each of them has a different environment and rules. There might be some connectivity issues with the providers that can lead to a timeout or even if many requests are sent towards a hotel they could block them.
- Did you make sure the hotel you tried to book had the right payment policy? The current version of the Hotel Booking API only supports [credit card payments](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/developer-guides/resources/hotels/#notes-about-payment). The Hotel Search API returns the payment policy of each hotel under acceptedPayments in the policies section.
- Also, the credit card has already expired in the past.